# How to get the % of items by type using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, window-functions

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE item_color (
    item_id INTEGER,
    color VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE item_info (
    item_id INTEGER,
    type INTEGER
);


INSERT INTO item_info (item_id, type)
VALUES
  (57510, 7),
  (57509, 7),
  (57508, 8),
  (57507, 8),
  (57506, 7),
  (57505, 7),
  (57504, 8),
  (57503, 8),
  (57501, 8),
  (57500, 8),
  (57499, 7),
  (57498, 7),
  (57497, 8);

INSERT INTO item_color (item_id, color)

VALUES
  (57510,'Red'),  (57509,'Red'),  (57508,'Green'),  (57507,'Blue'),  (57506,'Red'),  (57505,'Red'),
  (57504,'Red'),  (57503,'Green'),  (57501,'Blue'),  (57500,'Red'),  (57499,'Green'),  (57498,'Blue'),
  (57497,'Red'),  (57510,'Red'),  (57509,'Red'),  (57508,'Red'),  (57507,'Red'),  (57506,'Red'),
  (57505,'Red'),  (57504,'Red'),  (57503,'Red'),  (57501,'Blue'),  (57500,'Red'),  (57499,'Red'),
  (57498,'Red'),  (57497,'Red'),  (57510,'Green'),  (57509,'Red'),  (57508,'Red'),  (57507,'Red'),
  (57506,'Blue'),  (57505,'Red'),  (57504,'Green'),  (57503,'Red'),  (57501,'Blue'),  (57500,'Red'),
  (57499,'Red'),  (57498,'Red'),  (57497,'Red'),  (57510,'Green'),  (57509,'Green'),  (57508,'Red'),
  (57507,'Red'),  (57506,'Blue'),  (57505,'Red'),  (57504,'Green'),  (57503,'Green'),  (57501,'Blue'),
  (57500,'Blue'),  (57499,'Blue'),  (57498,'Blue'),  (57497,'Blue'),  (57510,'Red'),  (57509,'Red'),
  (57508,'Red'),  (57507,'Red'),  (57506,'Red'),  (57505,'Red'),  (57504,'Red'),  (57503,'Red'),
  (57501,'Red'),  (57500,'Red'),  (57499,'Red'),  (57498,'Red'),  (57497,'Red');
```

**item_info**

```
item_id type
57510   7
57509   7
57508   8
57507   8
57506   7
57505   7
57504   8
57503   8
57501   8
57500   8
57499   7
57498   7
57497   8
```

**item_color**

```
item_id  color
57510   "Red"
57509   "Red"
57508   "Green"
57507   "Blue"
57506   "Red"
57505   "Red"
57504   "Red"
57503   "Green"
57501   "Blue"
57500   "Red"
57499   "Green"
57498   "Blue"
57497   "Red"
57510   "Red"
57509   "Red"
57508   "Red"
57507   "Red"
57506   "Red"
57505   "Red"
57504   "Red"
57503   "Red"
57501   "Blue"
57500   "Red"
57499   "Red"
57498   "Red"
57497   "Red"
57510   "Green"
57509   "Red"
57508   "Red"
57507   "Red"
57506   "Blue"
57505   "Red"
57504   "Green"
57503   "Red"
57501   "Blue"
57500   "Red"
57499   "Red"
57498   "Red"
57497   "Red"
57510   "Green"
57509   "Green"
57508   "Red"
57507   "Red"
57506   "Blue"
57505   "Red"
57504   "Green"
57503   "Green"
57501   "Blue"
57500   "Blue"
57499   "Blue"
57498   "Blue"
57497   "Blue"
57510   "Red"
57509   "Red"
57508   "Red"
57507   "Red"
57506   "Red"
57505   "Red"
57504   "Red"
57503   "Red"
57501   "Red"
57500   "Red"
57499   "Red"
57498   "Red"
57497   "Red"
```

I am trying to a query to return the % of items by type that is either green or blue in the items.

**Desired Output**

```
type  percent_blue_green  total_items
7         30.00               6
8         34.29               7
```

I wrote a very complex query to get the output like this

```
SELECT subquery1.type,
       ROUND( CAST((CAST(subquery3.blue_green_colors AS FLOAT) / CAST(subquery2.total_colors AS FLOAT) * 100) AS numeric), 2) AS percent_blue_green,
       subquery1.total_items
  FROM (SELECT type,
               COUNT(item_id) AS total_items
          FROM item_info
         GROUP BY type) AS subquery1
          JOIN (SELECT type,
                       COUNT(color) AS total_colors
                  FROM item_info AS si1
                       JOIN item_color AS sal1
                         ON sal1.item_id= si1.item_id
                 GROUP BY type) AS subquery2
            ON  subquery2.type= subquery1.type
          JOIN (SELECT type,
                       COUNT(color) AS blue_green_colors
                  FROM item_info AS si2
                       JOIN item_color AS sal2
                         ON sal2.item_id= si2.item_id
                 WHERE color IN ('Blue', 'Green')
                 GROUP BY type) AS subquery3
            ON  subquery3.type= subquery1.type;
```

I am still learning SQL. Is there a simpler and efficient way to write a SQL query that gets me the desired output.

Comment: Could you please post the code to build the database?

Comment: So a given item may have more than one color? You should give more details on the ruls of the computation.

Comment: @bhristov I added the query to create the tables.

Comment: @GMB Each item id is unique and exists across both tables and a given item can have more than one color. I am only interested to see what is the percentage of blue & green from the total colors across the 2 types (7,8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
select 
    i.type,
    avg( (c.color in ('Blue', 'Green'))::int ) ratio_blue_green,
    count(distinct i.item_id) no_items
from item_info i
inner join item_color c on c.item_id = i.item_id
group by i.type
```

The second value is a value between 0 and 1 that represents the *ratio* of blue and green over all colors of the type; you can easily turn it to a percent and format it as needed (as for me, I find that the information is easier to understand this way).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b67ad78f4ba12bcf3c0b86bb68654076)**:

```
type |       ratio_blue_green | no_items
---: | ---------------------: | -------:
   7 | 0.30000000000000000000 |        6
   8 | 0.34285714285714285714 |        7
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I really appreciate it. I am trying to understand the usage of "::int" in row 3. Can you explain to me what that row does? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Sharath: this evaluates the condition as `1` when succesful, else `0`. Taking an average of this gives you the ratio of rows that satisify the condition.